# haskell/gloss example error w/ GLUT dynamic library "Symbol not found: _glutBitmap8By13 error"

Tags: macos, haskell, opengl, glut, gloss

When I load the haskell / gloss examples (so far I've tried Wave and Snow), I seem to be getting an error with finding something in the GLUT shared libraries. What might cause this error and how can I fix it?

```
can't load .so/.DLL for: /Users/jd/sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/GLUT_J2ZZFJOYOcH4hQYFlXhEPp/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.1-0waW9bZutCf5s5H5zSV4Oh-ghc7.10.1.dylib (dlopen(/Users/jd/sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/GLUT_J2ZZFJOYOcH4hQYFlXhEPp/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.1-0waW9bZutCf5s5H5zSV4Oh-ghc7.10.1.dylib, 5): Symbol not found: _glutBitmap8By13
  Referenced from: /Users/jd/sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/GLUT_J2ZZFJOYOcH4hQYFlXhEPp/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.1-0waW9bZutCf5s5H5zSV4Oh-ghc7.10.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/jd/sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/GLUT_J2ZZFJOYOcH4hQYFlXhEPp/libHSGLUT-2.7.0.1-0waW9bZutCf5s5H5zSV4Oh-ghc7.10.1.dylib)
```

This is on mac OSX 10.9.5 with GHC 7.10.1

Comment: According to the [GLUT issue tracker](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/issues/19), this a GHC bug.

Comment: I have the same problem. Works fine in GHC 7.8.x tho.

Comment: anyone know if it's been fixed in the current RC for 7.10.2? Hopefully the RC will be available at https://ghcformacosx.github.io/ soon.

Comment: @daj Not yet fixed, see: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10568